# fetch: 'join' ignored

Tags: grails, grails-orm

**Setup:**

3 Domain classes A, B and C. A and B are in a plugin. C is in an application which depends on this plugin.

```
class A{
    B b
    static mapping = {
        b fetch: 'join'
    }
    ...
}

class C extends A{
    String name
    ...
}

C.list().each{
    println it.b.name
}
```

**Problem:**

As described in the documentation (http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/fetch.html)  fetch: "join"  should force hibernate to use only one query for each println line. Unfortunately there are two select queries without join.

**My Investigations**

I have created a fresh Grails project and it works as described in the documentation, but class A is not in an external plugin.

**Question**

Any idea why fetch: "join" is ignorred in the example above?

Comment: "I have created a fresh Grails project and it works as described in the documentation, but class A is not in an external plugin." can you explain more?

Comment: In the description of my problem is, that the class A is an external plugin. In my try the domain A is part of the application. That is the difference.

Comment: How can A to use B if A is an external plugin?

Comment: Something is strange here. A and B exists in a plugin? If not, how can you compile the A domain class without the B?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right! I've corrected the code above.

Comment: What happens if you fetch A (without extending it with C) and do a.list().each { .. } ?

Comment: For the project it doesn't work. In the clean try (see My Investigations) it works.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.x, fetch/eager joins are ignored when using a criteria.

See this bug report: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9829

This is a fairly big problem but it is due to Hibernate3 so not easily solved in Grails.

You need to use HQL to be able to fetch/eager join.